# How to connect to my desktop from Linux debian Azure VM,

Tags: linux, azure, connection

I have a license server on a local desktop computer in my office; I should be able to connect to it thanks to its ip-adress and port. But it does not work.
To understand why, I tried running command:

```
telnet 137.999.999.999 11111
```

But I get the follwing message:

```
Trying 137.999.999.999...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

How can I make my Linux Debian Azure VM be able to connect to my desktop computer which host the license manager ?

Comment: That 137.999.999.999 IP address looks very interesting.

Comment: Haha, of curse it is for the example ^^

Comment: Firewall? Routing? Impossible to tell from the information you've provided here.

Comment: @AndrewSchulman Firewall should not be a problem since I can access my license from any other computer that are not in Azure. I have no clue what I should look for or check. What do you mean by routing ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, it seems Azure **NSG** or Debian **firewall** block it.

Please check NSG settings via Azure portal, check virtual network NSG inbound rules and subnet NSG inbound rules.

Also you should check Debian firewall settings, make sure port 11111 allowed in that inbound rules.